# ¿Que patrón de promesas debo usar en este caso?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promesas

Estoy usando el servicio `$resource` de Angular para obtener datos de una API, de la siguiente manera:

```
var getAccountListPerUser = function () {

  return $resource(uri, {}, {
    get: {
      headers: service.getDefaultHeaderRequest(),
      method: 'GET',
      transformResponse: function (data) {
        var accountList = [];
        try {
          accountList = JSON.parse(data);
        } catch (e) {
          accountList = [];
        }
        return accountList;
      },
      isArray: true,
      cache: true
    }
  }).get().$promise;
};
```

En mi controlador tengo que usar esta función y otras dos definidas de la misma manera para traer más información.

```
var promiseResourcesAccountList = usrWebUserService.getAccountListPerUser();

promiseResourcesAccountList.then(function(result){
  $scope.usersWithAccountsAndProfiles = result;
  var filteredProfiles = [];
  for (var account in result) {
    ...
  }
  $scope.filteredProfiles = filteredProfiles;
});
```

Y:

```
var promiseResourcesEditUser = usrWebUserService.getResourcesUser(currentUser);

promiseResourcesEditUser.then(function (result) {
  usrWebUserFactory.mapBasicPreferences($scope, result);
});
```

Y luego otra muy similar, esta información carga datos en tres `<divs>`, pero quiero mostrarlos sólo cuando las tres funciones se hayan completado correctamente.

Pienso que debo encadenar los resultados de las promesas. ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Encadenar** no es lo que quieres. [Encadenamiento](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/#chaining) se refiere a lo siguiente

```
promesa.then(function() {
    // Se retorna una promesa o un valor
    return siguientepromesa();
}).then(function() {
    // que es manejado en el siguiente método then
    return siguientepromesa();
}).then(function() {
    // última promesa
}).catch(function() {
   // manejo de errores
});
```

Lo que significa que cada promesa que le sigue se ejecutará cuando la **anterior haya terminado**. Además de eso si alguna de las promesas *siguentes* falla se interrumpe la cadena pero el código de cada uno de los `then` anteriores a ella ya se ejecutó.

En tu pregunta pones

> pero quiero mostrarlos sólo cuando las tres funciones se hayan completado correctamente

Lo cual define que el encadenamiento no es la solución adecuada para tí.

**Combinar** es la solución adecuada en tu caso. [Combinación](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/#combination) se refiere a

```
libreria.all([
    promesa(),
    otrapromesa(),
    otrapromesamas()
]).then(function(resultado) {
    // resultado es un arreglo con todos los datos recibidos
    // en el mismo orden en el que escribiste las promesas
    // [promesa, otrapromesa, otrapromesamas]
}).catch(function(err) {
    // Manejo de errores
});
```

La variable `libreria` se refiere precisamente a eso, la implementación de promesas que estas usando. En caso de angular se refiere a [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Desafortunadamente la librería `$q` no cuenta con un metodo [`spread`](https://github.com/showpad/angular-q-spread) sino podrías hacer algo como esto

```
libreria.all([
    promesa(),
    otrapromesa(),
    otrapromesamas()
]).spread(function(promesa, otrapromesa, otrapromesamas) {
    // los resultados vienen como parametros separados
    // mas simple de manejar ¿verdad?
}).catch(function(err) {
    // Manejo de errores
});
```

También puedes usar un objeto para combinar

```
libreria.all({
    prom1: promesa(),
    prom2: otrapromesa(),
    prom3: otrapromesamas()
}).then(function(resultado) {
    // resultado es un objeto con las llaves 
    // { 
    //   prom1: ..., 
    //   prom2: ...,
    //   prom3: ...
    // } 
    // con los resultados de las promesas
}).catch(function(err) {
    // Manejo de errores
});
```

Tu código puede ser escrito de esta forma

```
$q.all({
    accountPerUser: usrWebUserService.getAccountListPerUser(),
    resourcesPerUser: usrWebUserService.getResourcesUser(currentUser)
}).then(function(result) {
    $scope.usersWithAccountsAndProfiles = result.accountPerUser;
    var filteredProfiles = [];
    for (var account in result) {
        ...
    }
    $scope.filteredProfiles = filteredProfiles;
    usrWebUserFactory.mapBasicPreferences($scope, result.resourcesPerUser);
}).catch(function() {
    // error
});
```