# Guardar valor de funcion base64 en array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic, promesas

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación en ionic framework y necesito enviar el siguiente objeto mediante `$http` por método post.

```
$scope.project = {
      name: '',
      description:'',
      location: '',
      imgs: {},
      video: ''
  };
```

No tengo ningun problema con el nombre, la descripción ni la localización. El problema surge al querer almacenar imágenes en *base64* dentro de "imgs".

Para poder convertir las imagenes utilizo la siguiente función:

```
function toDataUrl(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        callback(reader.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
  }
```

Y de esta forma es como la llamo:

`allImages` es un array con las rutas de las imágenes.

```
if($scope.allImages.length>0){
   for (var i = 0; i < $scope.allImages.length; i++) {
        toDataUrl($scope.allImages[i], function(base64File){
            alert(base64File);
            //Guardar valor en base64 en el objeto.
            $scope.project.imgs[i]=base64File;
        });
   }
}

imprimeObjeto($scope.project.imgs);
```

Pero al ejecutar mi código lo que sucede es que, primero se muestra la impresión que hago hasta el final: `imprimeObjeto($scope.project.imgs);` y me muestra todo vacío, después muestra los alert con el código correcto en *base64* convertido en la función `toDataUrl, su puedo ver todo el codigo de la imagen en *base64*, pero este valor no es guardado en el array, o solamente guarda el valor de la última imagen seleccionada.

Lo que necesito es guardar el código en base64 dentro del objeto `imgs` algo así:

```
$scope.project = {
      name: '',
      description:'',
      location: '',
      imgs: {
              0 : 'codigoBase64blabla.....',
              1 : 'codigoBase64blaasdq....',
              2 : 'codigoBase64blablalbla.',
              3 : 'codigoBase64blabla.....',
              4 : 'codigoBase64blabla.....'
            },
      video: ''
  };
```

Pero por alguna razón, el codigo en *base64* sí es generado pero no guardado dentro del array.

Yo creo que tarda demasiado tiempo en convertir las imágenes y eso hace que se salte líneas de código. Existe alguna forma de que primero guarde las imágenes en *base64* dentro del objeto y no imprima primero lo del final?

Aun soy muy nuevo en angular, se puede hacer esto con promises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que estás usando la formula para convertir imágenes a *base64* que puede encontrarse en esta pregunta de StackOverflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript

En esta se usa `XMLHttpRequest` ya que es una formula de uso general. En tu caso estas usando angular y debes usar el servicio [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) que es de un nivel de abstracción mas alto que usar el API de javascript directamente, ya que si por ejemplo tienes algún interceptor habilitado, este dejará de funcionar en ese caso en particular.

Respondiendo a tu pregunta

> Existe alguna forma de que primero guarde las imágenes en base64 dentro del objeto y no imprima primero lo del final? Aun soy muy nuevo en angular, se puede hacer esto con promises?

Creo que estás en el camino correcto. La función `toDataUrl` contiene código asincrónico por lo que si tratas de imprimirla al momento no te dará ningún resultado.

Para arreglar esto debes retornar una promesa pero aquí debes usar lo que se conoce como

**Construcción explícita**

```
// Ya no es necesario el parámetro callback
function toDataUrl(url) {
    // Creas un nuevo objeto deferred
    var defer = $q.defer();
    // Usas el servicio $http para la petición
    $http.get(url, {responseType:'blob'}).then(function (response) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
            // resuelves la promesa con los datos leídos
            defer.resolve(reader.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(response.data);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // Rechazas la promesa en caso de error
        defer.reject(err);
    });

    // Retornas la promesa que acabas de crear
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Y luego las [combinas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20376/que-patr%C3%B3n-de-promesas-debo-usar-en-este-caso) usando [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

```
var promesas = [];
if($scope.allImages.length > 0) {
   for (var i = 0; i < $scope.allImages.length; i++) {
        promesas.push(toDataUrl($scope.allImages[i]));
   }
}

$q.all(promesas).then(function(imagenes) {
    for (var i = 0; i < imagenes.length; i++) {
        $scope.project.imgs[i] = imagenes[i];
    }
    imprimeObjeto($scope.project.imgs);       
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó bien